# Choose unique maximum value on excel

Tags: excel, max, unique

Lets say that I have `4,4,4,3,3,2` in my column on excel.
I want to choose the maximum but only once. (Only want one "4" to show up in a cell)
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MAX(). Inside max you can give the cell numers. I.e MAX(A1:A6)

Answer (score 0):

You would use:

```
=MAX(A1:A6)
```

I'm personally not a big fan of about help pages but this one seemed easy enough to follow.

http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/max_function.htm

Feel free to comment if you have any questions.